# Star-convex curve and Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, convexity, convex-analysis

Let x(t) be a periodic function on [0, 2$\pi$].
I am interested in finding criteria in terms of the Fourier coefficients of x(t), such that the parametric curve $\left\{ x\left( t\right) ,\dot{x}\left( t\right) \right\} $  is star-convex with respect to the origin.
Is this a problem with a known solution? Is there any literature on this problem?

My starting point is to see where such a parametric curve would "graze" a ray from the origin. The resulting trig equation is $x\left( t\right) \ddot{x}\left( t\right) -\dot{x}\left( t\right) ^{2}=0$.
I can find the multiplicity-2 (or higher) zeroes of this trig equation and this way I would have implicit hypersurfaces in the space of the Fourier coefficients that would "carve out" regions of star-convex shapes.

Comment: Is "star-convex" the same as "star-shaped"?

Comment: Yes. By star convex I mean a set that contains a point such that all line segments from that point to all points of the set is in the set.

Comment: But your set here is a curve, no?

Comment: For the curve it means that any ray from the origin intersects the curve in one point only.